# Babel JS is mixing function order

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I'm using the following Gulp code for using Babel. The code (application.js) is compiled correctly to ES5 (I just have an arrow function to test it).

However it is changing some functions order which is blocking me to open my page.

Any idea of what may be happening?

```
function buildBabelApplicationJavascript(){
  var stream = gulp.src(config.files.js.app)
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build_dir))
  return stream;
}
```

Comment: Do not concatenate JS, use a bundler like `browserify` if you need things put into a single file.